# Subversion seems to be storing my credentials but won't use them?

Tags: macos, svn

I recently upgraded my Mac. On my old Mac, SVN stored my passwords just fine. On the new one, it doesn't work. When I run the command 'svn auth' it shows that there is 1 credential in my keychain, and it is the right username, but when I use SVN it keeps prompting me for the password anyway.

I've examined all the config files and they are all correct.

I installed SVN from Homebrew. Should I be using another version?

Comment: Does it prompt you for your SVN password or for your macOS user account password? Could you please show an example of the prompt you are receiving? From SVNBook: *"... on Mac OS X, the Subversion client stores all repository passwords in the login keyring (managed by the Keychain service), which is protected by the user's account password. User preference settings can impose additional policies, such as requiring that the user's account password be entered each time the Subversion password is used."*. PS Since you installed the SVN client from homebrew, I assume that the version is SVN 1.14.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I found the problem. My SVN password was in the keychain, but the SVN app didn’t have permission to read it. I think this happened because I reinstalled SVN after migrating from an Intel Mac to an M2. The new SVN must have a different signature than the old one. I was able to fix it by telling Keychain to allow any process to read the entry.

Answer (score 0):

In similar fashion the problem I had was the keychain access for svn. Instead of allowing all programs I deleted the keychain entry for the svn password. Then when svn prompted me for a password I entered it and now the key chain had a new entry with proper access. One could also browse for and find the svn binary to allow access to only that but it was difficult for me to brows to the entry.